# Hosting an HTML, CSS, JS website on IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, hosting, cloud-foundry

I am trying to find a way of hosting a static site with my own domain name but I have not been able to find any clear tutorial on how I can do this. It's for a demo. The site has multiple html and css files, where can I get a good tutorial that can show me how to do this while learning at the same time?

Comment: watch this https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2014/08/deploying-static-web-sites/

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial seems to be what you're looking for:
[Deploy a Hello World webpage to IBM Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-a-hello-world-webpage-to-bluemix-app/index.html)

P.S. If you're looking for a free service to host your static site, I recommend [GitHub Pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Publishing_your_website#Publishing_via_GitHub) or [Google App Engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/How_do_you_host_your_website_on_Google_App_Engine). For one thing, IBM Cloud Lite plan offers only 256 MB of memory.